# Get Notified when upload is completed in Amazon S3 bucket

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Is there a way by which I can get notified when a upload is completed in S3 Bucket? The requirement is that I need to provide link to users after uploading of  a video is complete in the bucket. By default now I provide link after 30 minutes of start of video, whether video takes 5 minutes to upload or 40 minutes. So is there any way like any API that provides information that the upload has been completed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no direct method that can tell that whether the upload is complete or not in S3 bucket. You can do a simple thing which I have followed after lot of research and it is working correctly.

Follow this [link](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSDKforPHP/latest/index.html#m=AmazonS3/get_object_filesize) and read the size of file after every 30 seconds or so as per your requirement when the file size has not changed for two simultaneous readings once again check the size for surety because it might be due to network congestion that size might not have changed for two simultaneous readings.

Answer (score 16):

Notifications can be triggered in Amazon S3 when any of the following occur:

- `s3:ObjectCreated:*`
- `s3:ObjectCreated:Put`
- `s3:ObjectCreated:Post`
- `s3:ObjectCreated:Copy`
- `s3:ObjectCreated:CompleteMultipartUpload`
- `s3:ObjectRemoved:*`
- `s3:ObjectRemoved:Delete`
- `s3:ObjectRemoved:DeleteMarkerCreated`
- `s3:ReducedRedundancyLostObject`

Notifications can be sent via three destinations:

- **Amazon Simple Notification Service (SNS)**, which in-turn can send notifications via email, HTTP/S endpoint, SMS, mobile push notification
- **Amazon Simple Queueing Service (SQS)**
- **Amazon Lambda** (not currently available in all regions)

See: [Configuring Amazon S3 Event Notifications](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/NotificationHowTo.html)

The most appropriate choice depends on your programming preference and how your app is written:

- Use SNS to push to an HTTP endpoint to trigger some code in your app
- Write some code to periodically check an SQS queue
- Write a Lambda function in Node.js or Java

Once triggered, your code would then need to identify who uploaded the video, retrieve their user details, then send them an email notification. This would be easiest if you control the key (filename) of the object being uploaded, since this will assist in determining the user to notify.

Answer (score 3):

You can use Amazon Lambda to post a message to Amazon SNS (or notify you any other way) when a file is uploaded to S3.

1. Setup an S3 trigger to your Lambda function. See this tutorial: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/lambda/latest/dg/walkthrough-s3-events-adminuser.html
2. Inside your Lambda function, send out your notification. You can use SNS, SES, SQS, etc.

Comment: I can detect that a new file is being uploaded but I want a notification when upload is completed and not started.

Comment: Can't the S3 notification just go straight to SNS without having to go through Lambda?

Comment: @asusgates the Lambda will be triggered when the file is completed uploading.

Comment: @mbaird you are correct. S3 to SNS notifications: http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/ways-to-add-notification-config-to-bucket.html